# CP loads slow once in a while

Tags: control-panel, debugging, loading-time, toolbar

I have transfered a site to a new server and at the same time incorporated Focus Labs Master Config approach.

Now, since the site is running on the new server the CP loads really slow sometimes. It feels kinda like the URL is not being resolved correctly: link is being clicked, loading starts, it hangs, then new page "pops" up and loads normally. I hope you get the idea.

Until today I couldn't really find a pattern to this behaviour. Most of the time it works as expected but then once again I get this lag.

Also I am not saying that it must have anything to do with the new server or the Master Config. Those are just the two biggest changes I made.

However, I activated the EE Debug Toolbar 2 days ago and just got one of those lags after clicking on Template Manager. That's what it looks like:

[image]

After clicking on the 5th tab (with the 11.0590s) this is what's in there:

[image]

When I go back to Home and click Template Manager again I get a load time of 0.1978s.

I don't really know how to interpret the above values from the Debug Toolbar. Does somebody know or see what causes these lags?

Thanks and Cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Marc, we have/had been experiencing a similar issue. We first noticed after installing Memberr. On the hour, but not every hour during the day, we'd get a hang/freeze for 1-2 minutes.

So at 10:00 am any request to our ee site at two different office locations or any pc would simply stop/poll/loop call it what you want. Then at 10:02 am all requests simultaneous complete on all devices in both loctions. It got so bad, that if youd saved a template on one of the hours that it would poll ( yes there was a pattern) you cold go and get a coffee and be back before starting work again.

Thinking it was Memberr (because we noticed it first started after installing), we removed it and all cron jobs. We also suspected it was something to do with editing templates via cp.

The issue has now almost completely disappeared. We are on a shared server (and this could also be the cause). We still kept a log of incidents and have spoken to our host.